# Access handle to axes results with Invalid object handle

Tags: matlab

I am using the following callback function (see comments on each relevant line):

```
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)

% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%Call the calculation twice

[wv ,ff, tt] = calc_user_data(ear_vector(i)); %Call a function that prints some data using plot

save(store_file_name,'wv' ,'ff', 'tt');

axes(handles.axes2);
```

Before going to the function `calc_user_data` - Everything is OK with my handlers, and I can use them.

However, once back from the function, the attempt to use 'axes' on this handler fails with the message:

`Invalid object handle`

I understand that from some reason my handlers are being lost, and will appreciate if someone can explain how to avoid this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Seems strange, because you don't pass `handles` to the function, so it cannot delete or change it. Maybe by "print some data using plot" you close exist axes? Have you debugged it, or tried call `axes` before the function?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Hi, Regarding 'close exist axes' - I am using regular 'plot' command inside my function. In order to make sure this is not the issue, I removed all prints - but still no luck. Regarding the debugging - Yes I have debugged the issue, I can see that the value referring to 'axes2' is changed before and after the function call - but again I have no idea why is it happening. Regarding 'MWE' - I am not familiar with this acronym, can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you both ofcourse!